# How to reset mock/spy partially?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I want to reset only  method count in spy.

Is it possible?

I know that exists method

```
Mockito.reset
```

But it resets mock entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the way this is done is to set up the mock / spy in a `@Before` method so that for each test the behavior is the same but the count is always reset. If you need to reset the count mid-test, I suggest you create a method for setting up the behavior you need. Call `reset` then call the behavior setup method.

Another way of doing this MIGHT be to use an `Answer` to capture the method invocations, then reset the `Answer`.

```
private List<InvocationOnMock> invocationList = new ArrayList<>();



when(spy.someMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
   Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      invocationList.add(invocation);
      return null; // Or whatever you need to return
   }
});

// instead of reset
invocationList.clear();
```

Comment: Can you provide example of *Another way*

Comment: @gstackoverflow care should be taken when editing an answer. Was there really a need for the `final`? Does it make the answer better in some significant way? Or did you just edit it just for the purpose of having edited something? Is it possible that the final result would be to create a new list instead of clearing the existing list?

Comment: As I remember we cannot use non final parameters inside anonymous class. Please, correct me if I wrong

Comment: Parameters, true. I had intended that `invocationList` be a class field. Notice that `private` is not a valid parameter keyword (nor is assigning it a value `= new ArrayList<>()`)